# Salesforce 2 Salesforce Integration

Tags: integration

I have a requirement to get the SF clients information(User Licenses,Package Licenses) & update the Account object on the main SF org. The challenge here is that I cannot query Userlicense/PackageLicense as a normal Sobject(using Partner wsdl SOAP webservices).

What is the best approach to handle this? Any kind of suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We do have PackageLicense,UserLicense,Oraganization in API, Please check the following Links, you should be able to get all the information related Licenses. Please upvote if this Helps!

PackageLicense
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_packagelicense.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_packagelicense.htm)
UserLicense
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm)
Oraganization
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm)